# xy plot between strings and numbers

Tags: r

I spent lot of time searching for it, but couldnt find. Dont blast me if this is a basic question :)

I want to generate a scatter plot with below vectors

```
> x
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
> y
[1] 5 6 3 4
```

I used xyplot, but it gives below errors

```
> xyplot(y~x)
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
Warning messages:
1: In order(as.numeric(x)) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In diff(as.numeric(x[ord])) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In function (x, y, type = "p", groups = NULL, pch = if (is.null(groups)) plot.symbol$pch else superpose.symbol$pch,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: The answers below are fine.  Just wanted to point out that these are not "scatterplots," as that name is generally reserved for plotting one numerical value against another.  What you've got here is a variety of category plots (or factor plots), which show the frequencies, or values, associated with a collection of arbitrary labels.  The difference between a scatterplot and a category plot is that scatter implies the x-axis spacing has meaning, while category plots' x-axis is arbitrary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this.  Here is one suggestion from each of the main graphics libraries, i.e. base `graphics`, `lattice` and `ggplot2`:

---

In base graphics you can plot `factor(x)` against y:

```
plot(factor(x), y)
```

[image]

---

In `lattice`, you can use `dotplot`:

```
library(lattice)
dotplot(y~x)
```

[image]

---

And with `ggplot2` you can use either `qplot` or `ggplot` (after converting data to a `data.frame`):

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x, y)
ggplot(data.frame(x, y), aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to join the dots in dotplot with a line?

Comment: Yes, just specify the type: e.g. `dotplot(y~x,type="b")`

Comment: How can I plot two rows of data against the same categorical x-axis like in this plot: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230357/how-do-i-plot-this-data-using-r?noredirect=1#comment436097_230357

Comment: were you able to achieve this @TMOTTM?

Comment: @prabhatmishra Jup, see this guys solution here: http://qmviews.blogspot.ch/2016/08/r-plotting-multiple-categorical-data.html